# add CSS class to shiny textOutput

Tags: css, r, shiny, css-selectors

I need to add a CSS class to a series of textOutput in a shiny app.

When I try, e.g.:

```
textOutput('text', class = 'error')
```

I get:

```
Warning: Error in textOutput: unused argument (class = "error")
```

It is possible to alter the CSS of the id of that textOutput. However, my ids are generated dynamically, so that is not a good solution. A possible alternative would be to 'grab' all ids that begin with/contain "error" (e.g. "error1", "error2"), but I am not sure if this is possible within my CSS style sheet.

Comment: Do any of the `classFunc` functions from `shinyjs` help with this situation? https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/classFuncs.html

Answer (score 18):

A simple was to do this is using the shiny `tagAppendAttributes` function. I normally find it easier to pipe the HTML output of shiny output objects into it like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

textOutput("foo") %>% 
  tagAppendAttributes(class = 'error')
```

Which produces the following output, which contains the error class.

```
<div class="shiny-text-output error" id="foo"></div>
```

---

You can also do the same thing with styles

```
textOutput("foo") %>% 
  tagAppendAttributes(style= 'color:green;')
```

```
<div id="foo" class="shiny-text-output" style="color:green;"></div>
```

Comment: please do you know if we could also use the same technique "tagAppendAttributes" to add the style of a single specific table? I just tried the following but it doesn't do anything:
tableOutput("retail_dashboard_ratios_table") 
                                                  %>% tagAppendAttributes(style = '{
                                                 border-collapse: collapse;
                                                 font-size:20px;
                                                 color:red;}')

Comment: Try it without the braces:
`tableOutput("retail_dashboard_ratios_table") %>% tagAppendAttributes(style = 'border-collapse: collapse; font-size:20px; color:red;')`

Comment: Note that `tagAppendAttributes()` is not from the {shiny} package, it's re-exported by {shiny} from the {htmltools} package. So you'd require `library(htmltools)` if you're just looking for this function.

Answer (score 5):

The various `*Output` functions return objects with attributes you can manipulate, `class` among them -- just inspect their **str**ucture with the `str()` function:

```
foo <- textOutput("foo")
print(foo)
# <div id="foo" class="shiny-text-output"></div>
str(foo)
# List of 3
#  $ name    : chr "div"
#  $ attribs :List of 2
#   ..$ id   : chr "foo"
#   ..$ class: chr "shiny-text-output"
#  $ children: list()
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
```

This means that we can overwrite the `class` set by the `textOutput` function like so:

```
foo$attribs$class <- "foo bar"
print(foo)
# <div id="foo" class="foo bar"></div>
```

If you want to preserve existing classes while adding new ones, you can use the `paste()` function, and wrap it all in a custom `add_classes()` function for convenience:

```
add_classes <- function(el, classes) {
  el$attribs$class <- paste(el$attribs$class, classes)
  el
}

foo <- add_classes(foo, "baz qux")
print(foo)
# <div id="foo" class="foo bar baz qux"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe wrapping it in a div with the required class helps?:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(tags$div(id = 'wrap_div',
                         class = 'error',
                         textOutput('text')))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText ({
    "My text"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is to use a CSS selector like:

```
[id^="error"] {
   ...
}
```

This is placed within your external css file within the app directory...usually named style.css.

Comment: Could you please expand this answer ? Where do you put this code ? The full code would be appreciated.